# Memory leak in AWS Lambda when calling local folder

Tags: python, docker, lambda, dockerfile, huggingface-transformers

I have a python script that I'm currently using just to figure out how to use a docker container image and deploy it to lambda using a few libraries. The code is as follows:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print("Loading model...")
    model_path = './bart-large-cnn'
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path, local_files_only=True)
    model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_path, local_files_only=True)
    print("Loaded")

    text = "..."

    inputs = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus([text],return_tensors='pt', truncation=True, max_length=1024)
    summary_ids = model.generate(inputs['input_ids'], early_stopping=True)

    bart_summary = tokenizer.decode(summary_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

    print(bart_summary)

    return "Success"
```

I've saved the model 'bart-large-cnn' into the same directory, and this python function works just fine. My dockerfile is:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt
COPY app.py ./
COPY bart-large-cnn ./bart-large-cnn

CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

And after creating the docker container image, I checked the contents of the image to make sure that the bart-large-cnn folder was in there. The code ran fine in docker as well. However, when I upload to ecr and run in aws lambda, the code runs for a long time then quits due to the max memory being exceeded. The logs show that the last print statement before the exit was "Loading model..." so I know that the function gets stuck trying to load the model from the folder and has a memory leak, but I don't understand why, because I checked the docker image and the folder is there with all the correct files inside it.

Comment: That sounds like it could just be a symptom of exceeding some resource limit, not necessarily a leak _per se_.  If you run this application without Docker, how much local memory does it require to load the model file?

Comment: On my machine throughout the program it usually stays at 2GB ram, but I think it peaks at 4GB when loading the model, but it does so instantly while lambda runs for 5 minutes then exceeds memory. My lambda also doesn't let me allow more than 3gb ram, so I'm trying to work with that much. @DavidMaze

Comment: I think the default memory allocated for lambda functions on AWS is 128MB, but you should be able to allocate up to 10GB.  Note that allocating more memory will bring the cost up as  well.